# My color setup is locked on my aoc 27g1g4 monitor. how do you unlock it

Tags: windows

My color setup is locked on my aoc 27g1g4 monitor. how do you unlock it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per this](https://tw.aoc.com/upload_files/manual/g1series/C27G1%20English%20manual.pdf)  press and hold the menu button while the monitor is OFF, while doing so hit the power button.

Comment: I can stil not go to color setup. It just unlocks and locks osd

Comment: All the manuals say similar instructions.  After unlock, press menu button, then left or right buttons until you see the 3 color circles (red, green, blue.)  That should be the color setup menu.